# When using Singleton pattern for retrofit2, how can I gen different headers with interceptor?

Tags: android, retrofit, interceptor

I know, I can use @Header to for different headers.
But when I use singleton pattern for retrofit, is there any way to make different headers for requests with interceptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using an interceptor to intercept the request,there in intercept method you can write following to add the headers:

```
 Request originalRequest = chain.request();

    HttpUrl originalHttpUrl = originalRequest.url();
    HttpUrl newHttpUrl = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
            .build();

    Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .addHeader(AppConstants.AUTHORIZATION, AppConstants.TOKEN)
            .addHeader(AppConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, AppConstants.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .addHeader(AppConstants.REQUESTED_WITH, AppConstants.XML_HTTP_REQUEST)
            .url(newHttpUrl)
            .build();

    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
}
```

If you want the headers to be added with each request then you can do like this:

```
@Headers({
    "Accept: application/json",
    "User-Agent: Your-App-Name",
    "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"
})
@GET(ApiConstants.GET_WORKER_DATA)
Call<ArrayList<Worker>> getWorkerData();
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. `okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(an interceptor);`, there is one retrofit object. Then I want different kind of headers. After I get the only one object of retrofit, can I add the interceptor when using it, but not building it?

Comment: okay, I get it. I know I can use @Headers or (@Header("xxx") Srting x) for different headers.    \nThen, I think I can put rules in the XXXInterceptor.class to make different headers. like => `if(a) newRequestA; if(B) newRequestB; else originalRequest`

Comment: In the interceptor, you can use add headers which is common to every request. Use @head notation if you want to use some specific header for a particular request.

Answer (score 0):

You can add different header for each request by adding the header tag inside like that

```
 @GET("YourEndPoint")
    Call<YourClassName> YourFunctionName(@Header("Authorization") String accessToken) ;
```

Comment: Thanks! I know this way, and it is a good way, but I want to make clear whether interceptor can do this in a singleton pattern :D

Comment: [https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors]
you need to study this link.